# zsh no such file or directory shows in terminal while coding with codeblocks in MacBook Pro

Tags: c, macos, terminal, codeblocks

```
/Applications/CodeBlocks.app/Contents/MacOS/cb_console_runner DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:. /Users/sayeeba/study programming/LIVE/bin/Debug/LIVE 
sh: /Users/sayeeba/study: No such file or directory

Process returned 127 (0x7F)   execution time : 0.003 s
Press ENTER to continue.
```

This is what it shows in terminal whenever I try to run code in codeblocks. I have used this method in `environment>terminal` to launch by deleting 'quoted form of' part. But this is not working.

Comment: Do you have a directory called "study programming", with a space in the middle? That's a bad idea, unless you really know what you are doing, because so many things use spaces as separators.

Comment: You need to make CodeBlocks put your path in quotes to allow for spaces in it. Many programs don't expect that and cause trouble. After all, IMHO it's not worth the effort. Don't use spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Your `study programming` directory has a space in the name. Spaces become problematic when used in definition like:

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH:. /Users/sayeeba/study programming/LIVE/bin/Debug/LIVE
```

Notice it could no find `/Users/sayeeba/study` and return the "No such file or directory" error.

You could rename the directory to `study_programming` with an underscore instead of the space after study. Updating your path to use the underscore version should resolve the issue.